# Can't get deoplete to start in NeoVim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I've been trying to get autocomplete working for GoLang in NeoVim. When searching, I got brought to [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim). I'm using [dein.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim) as a NeoVim package manager. My `.vimrc` file is set with the following:

```
if &compatible
set nocompatible               " Be iMproved
endif

" Required:
set runtimepath^=/home/tyler/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim

" Required:
call dein#begin(expand('/home/tyler'))

" Let dein manage dein
" Required:
call dein#add('Shougo/dein.vim')

" Add or remove your plugins here:
call dein#add('Shougo/neosnippet.vim')
call dein#add('Shougo/neosnippet-snippets')
call dein#add('Shougo/deoplete.nvim')

" You can specify revision/branch/tag.
call dein#add('Shougo/vimshell', { 'rev': '3787e5' })

" Required:
call dein#end()

" Required:
filetype plugin indent on

" If you want to install not installed plugins on startup.
if dein#check_install()
    call dein#install()
endif

let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
```

I've done a lot of searching around the various github issues and haven't had any luck yet. To recap, the issue is that I can't seem to get the deoplete NeoVim plugin to autocomplete. Maybe I have a misunderstanding of how this is suppose to work.

Comment: You'll have higher chance of getting an answer if you describe what you're doing, what results you're expecting and what the actual result is.

Comment: Neovim, a neovim-only autocompletion plugin, an unknown plugin manager, a fuzzy question asked on a generic site instead of the proper issue tracker… You will need a lot of luck.

Comment: Have you got `:echo has("python3")` returning `1`? If yes, make sure you have done `pip3 install neovim` and try to point your neovim to both python hosts something like `let g:python_host_prog = '/usr/local/bin/python'` and 
`let g:python3_host_prog = '/usr/local/bin/python3'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Anzel provided a good answer here. the Python neovim interface needed to be installed via pip. For example `pip3 install neovim`. To try to clear the question up, I was attempting to get neovim to use autocomplete via the deoplete plugin. This wasn't working (auto complete wasn't being recommended in real time even though the option was specified) because the Python interface that was required, wasn't installed. After the python interface was installed, a simple